# Undefined Index in my dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm a newbie to PHP programming and I am in the module of using dropdown list. I was looking in the internet and try to copy some and study about it, but (nosebleed...) because I am just starting.. I get this error

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: `Notice Message: Undefined index: select1` ........

here's the code. I hope somebody helps to enlighten me.

```
        <label for="unit">Province</label><select name="select1" onChange="showState(this.value);">
            <option value=""> --- Select --- </option>              
            <?php
            while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $line['prov_id'];?>" <?php if($line['prov_id']==$_REQUEST["select1"]) { echo "selected"; } ?> > <?php echo $line['prov_name'];?> </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <?php
```

Comment: $_REQUEST["select1"] - Does this really exists. First check if it is set using isset() function or rather do a print_r($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition with,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["select1"]) && $line['prov_id']==$_REQUEST["select1"])
```

You required to check if variable is set or not before comparing it with another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that $_REQUEST["select1"] is set or not before using its value

```
<option value="<?php echo $line['prov_id'];?>" <?php if( isset($_REQUEST["select1"] ) && $line['prov_id']==$_REQUEST["select1"]) { echo "selected"; } ?> > <?php echo $line['prov_name'];?> </option>
```

Comment: it works too, wow thank you and i will keep studying about this more. i was thinking about trying to put another dropdown list just like country and state where you can select country and automatically query the state. I dont know how i hope i found out soon.